# Do I evoke problems if I call my own class "Vector"?

Tags: c#, namespaces

I want to build my own class `Vector` but a class with that name already exists in C#.
Can I name it `Vector` anyway or will I run into issues sooner or later?

Comment: That's what namespaces are for.

Comment: It begs the question: What's missing from Vector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is fine to have a duplicate class name, as long as it resides in another namespace.

So this is fine:

```
namespace Mine
{
    class Vector
    { }
}
```

Note that this could cause problems if you want to include the namespace of your own `Vector` class and the BCL one.

```
using Mine;
using System.Windows;

Vector v;
```

The type of `v` will be ambiguous now, so you have to supply the namespace:

```
Mine.Vector v;
```

This on itself isn't a problem, but it could get tricky when you are mixing things up.

Comment: I see so that means I can use both Vector classes in the same project file

Comment: Yes, you can. As long as you provide the namespace.

Answer (score 4):

It would be fine as long as the [namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k.aspx) is different from the existing `Vector` class.

Let's say you have this class

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Vector
    { 
        // properties here
    }
}
```

Here's how you differentiate between both namespaces

```
using MyNamespace;
using System.Windows;

public void MyMethod()
{
    // this refers to your Vector class
    MyNamespace.Vector v1;

    // this refers to the existing Vector class from System.Windows namespace
    System.Windows.Vector v2;
}
```

or you can also use alias namespace

```
using MyNamespace;
using OriginalNamespace = System.Windows;

public void MyMethod()
{
    // this refers to your Vector class
    MyNamespace.Vector v1;

    // this refers to the existing Vector class from System.Windows namespace
    OriginalNamespace.Vector v2;
}
```

Comment: Ah I see. So would I be able to call both my own `Vector`and the existing `Vector`in the same solution?

Comment: Yes, although you should specify which namespace you're referring to.

Comment: Yes you can, you could even have multiple `Vector` classes in your own solution.

Comment: Sure... You can then call Original.namespace.Vector and Your.Namespace.Vector or use alias namespaces